# Reading children tags in xaml (similar to ListBox's)

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, listbox, controls

in Silverlight listbox's can be populated either through an observablecollection class or xaml like so:

```
        <TextBox Name="tb" Text="DroplistBox" Width="140" Height="30"></TextBox>
        <ListBox Name="lb" Width="150" Height="200" SelectionMode="Single">
           <ListBoxItem>
                <TextBox Text="1" Width="140" Height="30"></TextBox>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <TextBox Text="2" Width="140" Height="30"></TextBox>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <TextBox Text="3" Width="140" Height="30"></TextBox>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <TextBox Text="4" Width="140" Height="30"></TextBox>
            </ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
```

So my question is, how can I duplicate this in a control of my own? So basically I'm not sure how I would go about parsing ListBoxItem's which exist inside ListBox. is tehre a sort of List FindChildren(string name) type function I should be looking for?

**I solved this with the help of foson's answer**, here's the gist of what I did if anyone was interested since I couldn't explain myself very clearly in my comment to foson's answer:

```
   [ContentProperty( "Items" )]
   public class ControlWithChildReader : Control
   {

      List<object> m_objects = new List<object>( );
      public object Items
      {
         get
         {
            return m_objects[ 0 ]; //probably not needed haha
         }
         set
         {
            m_objects.Add( value );

         }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replicate the behaviour that ItemsControl exibits by placing the following attribute on your collection

`[ContentProperty("Items", true)]`

This will add the XAML content to an Items collection property.

Comment: Ah that has helped a bit, I added ContentProperty( "Items" ) and a property to my class called TextBox Items, but I can only read one TextBox from the xaml this way. Is there a way of reading in all the textbox children or no?

Comment: Nevermind solved that by making the property add anything that gets set to it to a list :D

Answer (score 2):

This might help when dealing with templates and controls inside controls Consider this XAML:

XAML

```
    <ListBox Name="lb" Width="150" Height="200" SelectionMode="Single">
       <ListBoxItem>
            <TextBox Text="1" Width="140" Height="30"></TextBox>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <TextBox Text="2" Width="140" Height="30"></TextBox>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <TextBox Text="3" Width="140" Height="30"></TextBox>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <TextBox Text="4" Width="140" Height="30"></TextBox>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

If you're trying to get textboxes inside the listboxitems:

if there is a seledted listbox item and you want to access the TextBox inside :

```
ListBoxItem item1 = lb.SelectedItem;
Textbox tb1 = item1.GetVisualDescendants().OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
```

if you want to Get All Textboxes inside the whole list box:

```
List<Textbox> tbCollection = lb.GetVisualDescendants().OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
```

You could also try to use:

```
GetVisualAncestors(); - Gets all anscestor controls(parent of parent of the item)
GetVisualChildren(); - Gets all controls inside a controls which are in the control
GetVisualSiblings(); - Gets all controls that share the same parent with the control
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get this functionality by inheriting from the [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx) and then access the children through the [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.items.aspx) property.